# Float 2 divs and background image

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to float two divs and set background images to them. But the desired look I couldn't get.

This is what I wanna do
[image]

But this is what I get
[image]

My HTML

```
<div class="orange_bk">Outstanding</div> <div class="black_bk">Play</div>
```

css

```
.orange_bk{
    float: left;
background: url(../images/Outstanding%20button.png);
background-position: 8px -10px;
width: 45%;
height: 33px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
line-height: 23px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 15px;
}

.black_bk{
    float: right;
    background: url(../images/Play%20Button.png);
background-position: 8px -10px;
width: 45%;
height: 33px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
line-height: 23px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 15px;
}
```

These are the two images I used

[image]
[image]

Comment: How about `background: no-repeat url(../images/Outstanding%20button.png) 8px 0;` and remove all other instances of background

Comment: nope that doesn't help :(

Comment: can you make the live demo of your code with your images.... that would much easier for us to sort out your problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could ditch the images altogether and use `background: #fb892b;` for the orange and set a gradient over the top. Also use `border-radius` for the rounded corners

[Quick jsfiddle using gradients and border-radius](http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/3WCah/)

```
.orange_bk, .black_bk {
    color:#fff;
    float: left;
    background: #fb892b;
    width: 50%;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius:.25em 0 0 .25em;
    padding:.25em 0;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00));
}
.black_bk {
    float: right;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 0 .25em .25em 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set line-height to be the same as the height of the background (33px).
Also both divs have `width: 45%;` ..what do you want to do with the rest of 10% that the element that contains these elements has ?

Answer (score 1):

You can tidy this code up a lot and keep it much simpler. E.g. wrap an element around those two divs and do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

.wrap {
    width: 598px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap div {
    width: 50%;
    line-height: 58px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.orange_bk {
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/Outstanding%20button.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

.black_bk{
    float: right;
    background: url(../images/Play%20Button.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
<div class="orange_bk">Outstanding</div> <div class="black_bk">Play</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The orange div is simply to long for your orange BG. Try adding a max-width for .orange_bk!
You should also set id to display:block and add a padding-top, so that the text is vertically centered

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

body {
    color: white;   
}

.orange_bk{
    float: left;
background: url(r55XB.png);
width: 50%;
height: 26px;
padding-top: 7px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-align: center;
font-size: 15px;
}

.black_bk{
    float: right;
    background: url(tRfQv.png);
width: 50%;
height: 26px;
padding-top: 7px;

background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-align: center;
font-size: 15px;
}</style>
```

Using percentage values with a non-repeating background makes it look awkward when the window is sized normally so you may want to change something related to that.

Answer (score 0):

```
.main{width:400px;}

.orange_bk{
float: left;
background: url(r55XB.png);
/*background-position: 8px -10px;*/
width: 45%;
height: 58px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
line-height: 58px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 15px;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
color:#FFF;
}

.black_bk{
float: left;
background: url(tRfQv.png);
background-position: -119px 0px;
width: 45%;
height: 58px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
line-height: 58px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 15px;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
color:#FFF;
}
```

try this solution.....
and also please modify the images into same size